# Supplementary text for Hoffman & Kunze

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I’m going to start reading Hoffman & Kunze’s Linear Algebr. I was wondering if there are any supplementary texts which focus on the applied/numerical side of linear algebra. Also, it doesn’t have to be a single text as I don’t think there any which cover both numerical methods and applications. Thanks

Comment: Friedberg's text is suitable for a first course, has many applications, has better notations, and has a good amount of challenge problems

Comment: @user912011 While Friedberg does have many applications, it appears to focus more on the concepts of linear algebra rather than its applications. I have already taken a course on linear algebra and I will also be doing Hoffman and Kunze so I’m looking for a book which focuses only on applications, computational methods and numerical approximations

Comment: Try Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen and Bau